# alternate way to trigger reverse-i-search without pressing ctrl+r in bash

Tags: bash, search, keyboard-shortcuts, history

The reverse-i-search facility in bash is useful, but it is unlike most other bash commands in that it seems to be bound to a keybinding (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>). How can a user trigger this facility using an alias or typed-in command instead?

Comment: It is an interactive command, so it must be bound to something. Are you looking for history expansion/substitution?

Comment: Basically I am looking for the identical behavior of Ctrl-R, but with a way to type it in instead of triggering it with that exact keycombination. Nothing fancy, just ergonomics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reverse-i-search function is actually a readline function (reverse-search-history) and not a bash builtin function (man builtin or see [builtin commands in the bash reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands)). To my knowledge there is no way to call a readline function outside of binding it to a key.

You can see all the readline key binding to these function using "`bind -l -p`". The list of [bindable readline commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bindable-Readline-Commands) can be found in the reference manual as well.

You can always use the `history` command to get a list of the history and use `grep` to find what you are looking for. Myself I find this to be useful:

```
alias hists="history | grep -v '^ *[0-9]* *hists' | grep $@"
```

When I run `hists something` I get a list of all the commands that matches `something`. All I have to do is then do !# to run the command. For example:

```
bash-3.2$ hists emacs
   30 emacs
  128 emacs
  129 emacs
  204 emacs
  310 emacs .bash_history
  324 emacs Documents/todo.txt
bash-3.2$ !324
```

It's not exactly what you are looking for but it's as close as I can make it.

Comment: grepping history is exactly what I started using Ctrl-R to get away from .... nice answer anyway, though

Comment: This works well.  Thank you.  Only thing it cannot do is to match the beginning of the line, so I changed it to alias hists="history | cut -b8- | grep -v '^ *[0-9]* *hists' | cut -grep $@"

Answer (score 6):

If you look at the man pages for bash or history (3readline) under "History Expansion > Event Designators" you see commands for doing this type of thing.

```
!?prof?
```

would bring up the most recent command that contained "prof" and execute it immediately. If you want to print the command without executing it, you can append ":p"

```
!?prof?:p
```

In order to edit the command at the command line, using the example above, type:

```
!?prof
```

(don't press enter) and press M-^ (Meta-Caret - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>^</kbd>)

These use the expansion facility of bash. They only get the most recent match.

If you'd like to write scripts or aliases, take a look in the bash man page at the builtin commands "fc" and "history" (-p or -s). Also "shopt -s histreedit".

Here's an example alias:

```
alias dothis='`history -p "!?jpg?"`'
```

(those are backquotes just inside the single quotes).

You can do some cool "s/old/new" and other stuff with some of these commands, too.

Comment: what keyboard are `M-^`?

Comment: @milanHrabos That would be the Meta-key.  Try the Alt-key.