# ^word^replacement^ on all matches in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

To clarify, I am looking for a way to perform a *global* search and replace on the previous command used. `^word^replacement^` only seems to replace the first match.

Is there some `set` option that is eluding me?

Comment: documentation reference (tldr: quick substitution `^string1^string2` is equivalent to `!!:s^string1^string2` , use `!!:gs...` for global substitution): https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Event-Designators.html

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ echo oneone
oneone
$ !!:gs/one/two/    # Repeats last command; substitutes 'one' --> 'two'.
twotwo
```

Comment: Are you sure you typed it right? It works fine for me. (I'm using GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release.)

Comment: just tested on an older version of bash, and (unsurprising) it doesn't work: 

`$ echo $BASH_VERSION`  _(2.05.8(1)-release)_
`$ echo oneone`  _(out:  oneone)_
`$ !!:gs/one/two`  _(out: twoone)_
 ...
`$ echo $BASH_VERSION` _(out: 3.2.25(1)-release)_
`$ echo oneone` _(out: oneone)_
`$ !!:gs/one/two` _(out: twotwo)_ 

... General advice for all things bash? Use version 3+

Comment: what does `gs` mean here? global substitution?

Comment: @Zen: yes: global substitution.

Comment: If you want to minimize characters you don't need one of the exclamation points and the last slash: `$ cp foo.h bar.h`  `$ !:gs/.h/.cpp`   (executes: cp foo.cpp bar.cpp)

Comment: `gs` is the ghostscript interpreter for PostScript. This is not bash, but an external program. Use @l3x solution, which operates on a variable. For global replacement within that variable, start with a double slash `${VAR//pattern/replacement}`

Comment: @BrentFaust in this case, `gs` is not invoked directly, but it represents flags for the `!!:` command (which is `word designators`). `g` _causes changes to be applied over the entire event line_, and `s` _does string substitution_. Source: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Modifiers

Answer (score 7):

This solution uses Bash Substring Replacement:

```
$ SENTENCE="1 word, 2 words";echo "${SENTENCE//word/replacement}"
1 replacement, 2 replacements
```

Note the use of the double slashes denotes "global" string replacement.

This solution can be executed in one line.

Here's how to globally replace a string in a file named "myfile.txt":

```
$ sed -i -e "s/word/replacement/g" myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

Blending my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582726/alternate-way-to-trigger-reverse-i-search-without-pressing-ctrlr-in-bash/739464#739464) with John Feminella's you can do this if you want an alias:

```
$alias dothis='`history -p "!?monkey?:gs/jpg/png/"`'
$ls *.jpg
monkey.jpg
$dothis
monkey.png
```

The !! only does the previous command, while !?string? matches the most recent command containing "string".

Comment: That doesn't work at all. There was no command called monkey, so nothing in my history containing monkey

Answer (score 2):

this question has many dupes and one elegant answer only appears in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/116631/486961) of user @Mikel in unix se

`fc -s pat=rep`

this bash builtin is documented under the chapter [9.2 Bash History Builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-History-Builtins.html)

> In the second form, command is re-executed after each instance of pat
> in the selected command is replaced by rep. command is interpreted the
> same as first above.
>
> A useful alias to use with the fc command is r='fc -s', so that typing
> ‘r cc’ runs the last command beginning with cc and typing ‘r’
> re-executes the last command (see Aliases).

Answer (score 1):

A nasty way to get around this could be something like this:

Want to echo `BAABAA` rather than `BLABLA` by swapping L's for A's

```
$ echo "BLABLA"   
BLABLA
$ `echo "!!" | sed 's/L/A/g'`
$(echo "echo "BLABLA" " | sed 's/L/A/g')
BAABAA
$
```

Unfortunately this technique doesn't seem to work in functions or aliases.

Comment: Right. Additionally, that generates a costly fork. In an operation involving thousands of iterations, this would create a significant time drag.

Answer (score -1):

I test it on SUSE 10.1.
"^word^replacement^" doesn't work, while "^word^replacement" works well.
for a instance:

```
linux-geek:/home/Myworks # ls /etc/ld.so.conf   
/etc/ld.so.conf  
linux-geek:/home/Myworks # ^ls^cat  
cat /etc/ld.so.conf  
/usr/X11R6/lib/Xaw3d  
/usr/X11R6/lib  
/usr/i486-linux-libc5/lib=libc5  
/usr/i386-suse-linux/lib  
/usr/local/lib  
/opt/kde3/lib  
/opt/gnome/lib  
include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf  
linux-geek:/home/Myworks #
```

Comment: But that only replaces *one* instance of the word on the previous line (happens to be the command).  Try changing the line `ls /etc/passwd /etc/passwd` to `ls /etc/hosts /etc/hosts` with the `^^` substation method.