# Is it possible to replace previous command by '^' multiple times?

Tags: shell, terminal

In terminal, I can replace previous command by using '^' like:

```
$ ls -a 

$ ^a^l

$ ls -l
```

But, how can I replace multiple times? I mean:

```
$ ls a.jpg b.jpg c.jpg

$ /* something */

$ ls a.png b.png c.png
```

Comment: +1 for showing the `^a^b` syntax which is cool and new to me:)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149482/caret-search-and-replace-in-bash-shell

Comment: You cannot use `^a^l` as a replacement "in terminal".  It is valid syntax in `bash`,  `csh`, and many other shells, but it is invalid in `dash`, `ksh`, and many other shells.  The shell is not the terminal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [^word^replacement^ on all matches in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649070/wordreplacement-on-all-matches-in-bash)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
!:gs/jpg/png
```

Comment: infact, i found out ^foo^bar^ can do the same :)

Comment: @bitsMix That only replaces one of them.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is global replacements

```
!!:gs/jpg/png
```