# What does ^ do in BASH command?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm new to BASH commands and I'm following some video lectures. Could anyone tell me why `^ln^stat` gets "translated" into
`stat file.txt link_hard.txt` ? The same happens with `^stat^ls -l^` that becomes `ls -l file.txt link_hard.txt`(see pic)

`file.txt` is an empty file and `link_hard.txt` is an hard link to `file.txt`.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPMEn.jpg

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243317/bash-how-can-i-replace-a-string-in-a-previous-command

Comment: It's [history expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#History-Interaction) to replace the first instance of a string in the previous command with another string; a shorthand for `!!:s^string1^string2^`.

Comment: Notice that it just replaces the first instance. use `!:gs/string1/string2` to replace all instances.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2149482/3266847 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/649070/3266847 (but not exact duplicates - they know about `^`, but ask about something that substitutes all occurrences).